# Nagios 4: Can’t open /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

Tags: startup, nagios

I just upgrade my Nagios server to the latest version (4.0.1) on my Debian 7 system. When i start the daemon, i have the following error:

```
# /etc/init.d/nagios start
/etc/init.d/nagios: 20: .: Can't open /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
```

The /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions did not exist on my Debian system (and also on my Ubuntu 12.04 workstation).

What can i do to solve this issue ?

===
Update:

Just hack the startup script with the following command line:

```
sudo apt-get install daemon
sudo sed -i 's/^\.\ \/etc\/rc.d\/init.d\/functions$/\.\ \/lib\/lsb\/init-functions/g' /etc/init.d/nagios
sudo sed -i 's/status\ /status_of_proc\ /g' /etc/init.d/nagios
sudo sed -i 's/daemon\ --user=\$user\ \$exec\ -ud\ \$config/daemon\ --user=\$user\ --\ \$exec\ -d\ \$config/g' /etc/init.d/nagios
sudo sed -i 's/\/var\/lock\/subsys\/\$prog/\/var\/lock\/\$prog/g' /etc/init.d/nagios
sudo service nagios start
```

Works fine on my Debian server.

Comment: welcome on SO nicolargo! related nagios issue: http://tracker.nagios.org/view.php?id=460

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write your own init script. Copy /etc/init.d/skeleton to /etc/init.d/nagios and fill in the values in that file:

```
DESC="Nagios"
NAME=nagios
DAEMON=/usr/local/nagios/bin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="-d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg"
PIDFILE=/usr/local/nagios/var/$NAME.lock
```

I also commented these lines:

```
#[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME
```

and

```
       #start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
       #       || return 1
```

Don't forget to chmod +x /etc/init.d/nagios.

Have fun.

Answer (score 3):

Little add for ubuntu 12.04 [desktop] :

- 'runuser' program doesn't exist for debianLike, but 'su' instead,
- 'service' program is not located in /sbin but in /usr/sbin

Then Nicolargo's mods + some of mine :

```
sudo apt-get install daemon
sudo sed -i 's/^\.\ \/etc\/rc.d\/init.d\/functions$/\.\ \/lib\/lsb\/init-functions/g' /etc/init.d/nagios
sudo sed -i 's/status\ /status_of_proc\ /g' /etc/init.d/nagios
sudo sed -i 's/daemon\ --user=\$user\ \$exec\ -ud\ \$config/daemon\ --user=\$user\ --\ \$exec\ -d\ \$config/g' /etc/init.d/nagios
sudo sed -i 's/\/var\/lock\/subsys\/\$prog/\/var\/lock\/\$prog/g' /etc/init.d/nagios
sudo sed -i 's/\/sbin\/service\ /\/usr\/sbin\/service\ /g' /etc/init.d/nagios
sudo sed -i 's/runuser/su/g' /etc/init.d/nagios
sudo service nagios start
```

I also removed the '-d 10' option applied on killproc in the stop sequence (around line 94) to avoid error message on 'service nagios stop' call.

```
$Stopping nagios: Illegal option -d
/sbin/start-stop-daemon: signal value must be numeric or name of signal (KILL, INT, ...)
Try '/sbin/start-stop-daemon --help' for more information.
```

'joy!

Answer (score 1):

You've probably found a solution, but to answer the question:
One possible solution is installing Nagios 3.x from your package manager and then updating to 4 by compiling it from source. The new init script seems to be messed up, but the older one still works.
Source(german): http://www.monitoring-portal.org/wbb/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=29431&pageNo=2